# How do I get started in finance & market analysis?

Tags: finance, marketing, technical-analysis, learning

I'am currently new to bitcoin & doesn't any finance or market background, currently I got huge interest to how this currency system will affect our life, as I spend more and more time reading about bitcoin, then I feel I need more knowledge about how finance world work, and how to do market analysis.

Can you give me a point where I should start learning about finance especially the one is connected to this bitcoin things?

Comment: Are you asking to learn what types of information will help you in trading (speculating) on bitcoin or are you asking about factors relating to the currency's societal impact in general?

Comment: It's been ~1 month since this question was asked but I'm happy to announce that the [Economics StackExchange](http://economics.stackexchange.com/) site is now in public beta and might be a much better place for questions like this one :)

Comment: @DavidPerry unfortunately, it is now dead :/

Comment: Yes, but from their ashes arose [Personal Finance & Money](http://money.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3):

Market analysis usually consist of Fundamental Analysis and Technical Analysis.

I recommend http://www.babypips.com to get started with the the Technical Analysis.

Fundamentals consist of understanding how the economy is effected by news and business. Social psychology to specific events and can vary depending on what market your looking into.